# Assignment algorithm: how can I overcome this situation?

Tags: algorithm, variable-assignment

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

The situation I'm about to describe is from the following lecture: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUGIhEecipE at 32:00
the professor explains this problem, however he doesn't present any solution to it

Suppose we are having the following table. The rows represent the workers, the columns the assignments and the values the amount of time a worker needs to complete an assignment

```
3 1 1 4
4 2 2 5
5 3 4 8
4 2 5 9
```

Initially I find the min value of each row, and subtract it from all the other values of the same row. I do the same for the columns and I get the following result

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 2
0 0 3 4
```

now, an obvious solution is worker 1 takes the task 4, worker 2 the task 3, worker 3 the task 2, worker 1 the task 1

however, using a programming language you can't really find this. If I make arbitrary selections I may choose for example

worker 1, task 1
worker 2, task 2
and then I can't choose anything because the remaining costs are more than zero.

if I do the ticking process, I will basically have to tick all the rows and all the columns, so the values of the table won't really change.

My question is, how to overcome this problem? Is there any method that would help me achieve this?

Also, can you recommend me some easier method to solve the assignment problem? This whole ticking process and subtracting min/max sounds like not something of low time complexity

I'm trying to implement an algorithm but since I might have to deal with this kind of situation, I see no point of implementing something that will turn out to be wrong in the end

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the section "The algorithm in terms of bipartite graphs" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm, then you will see a method, using breadth-first search, that either finds a matching or finds constants to subtract from rows and columns. In the example you quote, it should find a matching.

I don't see it quoted in the Wikipedia article on the assignment algorithm, but from memory I thought the Hungarian algorithm was a pretty competitive algorithm for this problem.

Comment: mcdowella: I feel you're a kind of expert for assignment/matching algos. I thought you might help me with [my old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870551/need-pairing-algorithm-based-on-hungarian?rq=1) which haven't been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: I don't claim to have extensive experience in this subject, but I have jotted down a few ideas against your question for you to think about.